# Mysql запрос '=' работает некорректно

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Я делаю такой запрос к бд mysql:

```php
$buy_info = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT DISTINCT `user_name`, `price`, `size`, `link`, `pay`, `limit_min`, `limit_max`, `time`, `color` 
    FROM `RUB`
    WHERE
        price = (
           SELECT MIN(`price`) 
           FROM `dress` 
           WHERE `color` LIKE '%blue%' 
               AND `size` = '52' 
               AND `limit_min` = 40000"
        )
```

То есть хочу вывести только значения, в которых колонка limit_min равна 40000. Но вместо этого мне просто выводятся все значения, игнорируя это условие. НО. Если я введу значение 35000, которого вообще нет в таблице, то не выведется абсолютно ничего. То есть это условие есть и скрипт его видит, но почему-то работает неверно.

Вывожу в php через цикл

```php
while ($pay_buy = mysqli_fetch_assoc($buy_info)) {
    echo $pay_buy['user_name'];
    echo " >>> ";
    echo $pay_buy['price'];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Кто писал запрос то?

Comment: в предыдущих вопросах помогли его написать. Была проблема с искючениями повторений. Получился в итоге такой запрос

Comment: Тогда добавьте контекста(например структуру таблиц приведите), сейчас в запросе не понятно как таблицы связаны

Comment: тьфу, я понял где вы ошиблись, можете не приводить контекст

Comment: Буду рад узнать в чем :) Так же на всякий случай добавил контекста всё же

Comment: Готово :) я ответ оформлял :) но я вас сразу предупреждаю, это решение - не очень хорошее (или я так считаю потому что не вижу реальной структуры таблиц, всмысле решение которое есть у вас) p.s. контекста не вашего php кода, а структуры таблиц :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я верно понял что вам выводит запрос, и что нужно то примерно так:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  `user_name`, 
  `price`, 
  `size`,
  `link`,
  `pay`,
  `limit_min`,
  `limit_max`,
  `time`,
  `color` 
FROM
  `RUB`
WHERE
  `limit_min` = 40000  /*фильтр нужно писать не в подзапросе*/
  AND price = (
               SELECT 
                 MIN(`price`)
               FROM
                 `dress`
               WHERE 
                 `color` LIKE '%blue%' 
                 AND `size` = '52'
               )
```

Comment: Да!! Это сработало, спасибо!)